# How would I find the MLE estimation for the parameter r in a negative binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I have a sequence of iid negative binomial random variables with a known p parameter but unknown r parameter. In other words we know what the probability of success of a given trial is, but we do not know how many successes are needed to stop the experiment. The pdf of the distribution is:

$f(x)$=$x_i-1\choose r-1$ $p^r$$(1-p)^{x_i-r}$  for $x_i\geq r$.

I am unsure how exactly to perform the MLE estimation procedure for this function when searching for an estimator of r. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: First, take logs to make everything easier. Once you do that, just take the derivative with respect to $r$. You will notice, however, that you must take the derivative of a factorial which yields a complicated expression (google diagamma function for more details). If the solution is not an integer ten you can round at your convenience.

Comment: First you need to multiply the pdfs together. Then perhaps consider the ratio f(x;r+1)/f(x;r) and see where it equals 1.